# when doing psql copy as select from table to csv file seeing high writeiops

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, provisioned-iops

When doing a psql copy to csv by selecting from table . we are seeing high write iops compared to read iops . What causes the high
 write iops when writing to causes file instead of db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most plausible explanation for heavy writes ocurring during seq scans is the hint bits feature.

From https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hint_Bits :

> PostgreSQL's MVCC mechanism provides a lot of useful features, but
>   there are some confusing side effects of the implementation. One
>   revolves around hint bit processing, which can result in **heavy writes
>   to a database table even though you're just reading from it**.